# Using bare infinitive with verbs such as "see", "watch", etc.: Present tense or Past Tense?

Tags: tense, aspect, bare-infinitives, verbs-of-perception

I know using the bare infinitive after verbs such as ***hear***, ***see***, ***watch***, etc. conveys  a different meaning from using the present participle (verb+ing):

> - I watched him climbing over the fence ( Climbing wasn't finished at the moment of speaking)
> - I watched him climb over the fence ( Climbing was finished at the moment of speaking)

I noticed the majority of the Grammar books use past tense to explain the aforementioned difference. Personally, I think that is quite rational because the bare infinitive implies a completed or finished occurrence. This means that event belongs to the past. However, I have a problem conceiving similar sentences in the present tense. For example:

- *[An uneasy feeling comes over me as **I watch him walk** towards the revolving doors](https://books.google.com/books?id=LNwYBpUcJYwC&pg=PA34&dq=%22I%20watch%20him%20walk%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-47bnwe7OAhXDhiwKHUEgBiUQ6AEIQzAH#v=onepage&q=%22I%20watch%20him%20walk%22&f=false).*

The questions is:

> If the bare infinitive implies a completed action, then why should we use the **present tense** to talk about that event? (the event is in the past).
>
> We can say that:
>
> *An uneasy feeling came over me as **I watched him walk** towards the revolving doors*

---

**Added info 1**

If you think my "climbing" examples are irrelevant, you can check Cambridge Advanced Grammar In Use, page 60, Unit 30, Section D or just check this [link](https://books.google.com/books?id=NY8oAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=Cambridge%20advanced%20grammar%20in%20Use%20Unit%2030%20section%20D&pg=PA60#v=onepage&q&f=false)

---

**Added info 2**

My question is from the logical point of view. I think the act of "seeing" is instantly. Therefore, it is not rational to say "see" a "completed process" but, "saw" a "completed process".

Comment: "I watched him climb over the fence (Climbing was finished at the moment of speaking)" - That's not a distinction I would make.  One could just as easily say "**As** I watched him climb over the fence..." which obviously implies that the climbing is *not* finished.

Comment: There is no implication with the bare infinitive that the observed action has been completed. *I watched him climb the stone arch freestyle ... until he lost his grip and fell into the river below.*

Comment: FWIW, it's not really about finished vs. incomplete. It's more like a whole view vs. a zoomed view.

Comment: @Cardinal I think this is an excellent question, +1 . However, I don't know exactly what you mean by "conceive" in _I have a problem conceiving similar sentences._ What sense of _conceive_ do you intend here? (note: you had the infinitive "to conceive" originally.)

Comment: Don't believe everything you read. "I saw him **smash**  the bottle" is understood to be a completed action only because semantically the smashing of a bottle occurs suddenly.  The bare infinitive does not *impart* that meaning; it merely is a better choice than the progressive when the verb refers to an action which happens instantaneously. "I watched him *popping* the soap-bubble" would be odd. We can say "I watched the phlebotomist draw blood until I could not look any longer" without there being any implication that the vials have been filled.

Comment: @Cardinal I am convinced that your real understanding of the subtle distinction here revolves around your meaning when you say you have trouble _conceiving_ similar sentences in the present. What verb in your first language do you mean by _conceive_ in English?

Comment: @P.E.Dant Thanks for your attention. 1. my meaning of "conceiving" is "forming an (logical) idea (image) in my mind ". I think you somehow understood the main concern of the sentence although I provided a very bad formatted question (I was in hurry). 2. My question was from the logical point of view. I though "see" means you see at the moment it's a very short-lived experience. therefore, it is not rational to say "see" a "completed process" but, "saw" a "completed process"; you can also check my discussion in the chat room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32060777#32060777

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between bare infinitive and gerund (-ing) is one of aspect, not tense. The bare infinitive looks at an action as a signal point in time whereas the gerund looks at it as a process (which is currently happening).

> I watched him climbing over the fence

This means at the moment you watched him, the act of climbing was still in progress. Compared to:

> I watched him climb over the fence

This view the action as a signal point without a beginning or end. This distinction is typically called the imperfective vs perfective aspect.

The bare infinitive doesn't imply a completed action, but rather a *complete* action without further structure or detail.

Thus,

> An uneasy feeling came over me as I watched him walk towards the revolving doors

means the uneasy feeling occurred as the speaker watched the act of walking in its entirety.

For many circumstances, the differences between the bare infinitive and the gerund will be slight.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what does "the two" refer to? the present and past? what about this: "I saw him smash the bottle" Doesn't imply a finished event?

Comment: the two = bare infinitive vs gerund. "I saw him smash the bottle" only represents a finished event because saw is past. "I will see him smash the bottle" doesn't represent a finished event, but it represents a completed total event.

Comment: Ok, what do you think about an action which has completed? Isn't it finished ?

Comment: I meant "but it represents a complete total event" not "completed". For example, "I heard him singing a song" vs. "I heard him sing a song" The first one implies hearing an act of singing by him, but does not imply that I heard the entire song. It also implies the singing is in progress; it started before I heard and continued after. The latter sentence suggests I heard the entire song.

Comment: Fine, I think my problem revolves around the definition of the "complete". I think, considering an event, "complete" means something has a beginning and a finishing.

Comment: completed and finished are roughly equal, but complete means whole, entire, etc. It's not that a complete action didn't start or end; it's that the action is viewed as a single indivisible action. "I walked" vs "I am walking". With more complex sentences the differences can be more apparent: "I walked five miles" vs "I was walking five miles"; the latter sounds incomplete since you are talking about an action in progress, so you'd expect something to "interrupt"

Comment: @Cardinal In "I saw him smash the bottle," the point in time of the speaker is after the event: the present. The speaker witnessed the entire (completed) event. In "I saw him smashing the bottle," the time perspective of the speaker is still the present, but his _description_ is concurrent with the event as it takes place.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I thought a completed action means a finished action, therefore it is not logical to say I "see", but I "saw".  I mean my problem is with "See" rather than the difference between using "bare infinitive" or "verb+ing".