# What tense of the word sing completes the sentence below appropriately?

Tags: tense, reported-speech

Which of the verb tenses of the word 'sing' appropriately completes the sentence:

> She said that she heard Esther ______.

In my study of the concept of reported speech I got to understand that a statement of this nature, when reported, carries past tense of the verb. But still after checking with online grammar software I am tempted to believe that the verb tenses 'sing', 'sang' and 'sung' can all appropriately complete the sentence. This of course is the root of my confusion.

Comment: Is this a homework question? What do you think the answer is?

Comment: "sing" -- but this question will be removed unless you edit your answer to ask why you are having trouble.

Comment: In my study of the concept of reported speech I got to understand that a statement of this nature, when reported, carries past tense of the verb. But stil after checking with online grammar software I am tempted to believe that the verb tenses 'sing', 'sang' and 'sung' can all appropriately complete the sentence. This of course is the root of my confusion.

Comment: @EnglishMaster - Firstly, do not trust grammar-checking software.  English grammar is very difficult for software to understand correctly, and grammar-checking software makes a lot of mistakes.  I see the source of your confusion now - tense changes in reported speech are tricky.  To see what verb form would be correct, think of how you would phrase the original sentence: She said, "I hear Esther ___."  The verb tense that gets changed is the main one, *hear*, not the other one.

Comment: That's a good one @stangdon - yet what if the original sentence is: She said, "I heard Esther sang"?

Comment: @EnglishMaster "I heard Esther sang" is wrong as a standalone sentence. To chagne "I hear Esther sing" to past tense, you only change hear to heard. There are cases where sang would appear there as part of a longer phrase, for example "I heard [that] Esther sang at the concert", but here the sentence is "I heard [that] <subordinate clause>", and the clause is "Esther sang at the concert".

Comment: @zstewart - "I heard Esther sang" could be correct as a reduced form of "I heard **that** Esther sang", as you point out, so it's possible that she said it.  In that case, I would say that the reported version would be "She said that she **had heard** that Esther **had sung**."

Comment: @stangdon I don't think you (necessarily) need to go to the past perfect there, "She said she heard Esther sang" could be valid, but would still of course have a different meaning from "She said she heard Esther sing". If you want to be explixit on the sequencing you can use more different past forms: "She said she **had heard** that Esther **had sung**"

Comment: @EnglishMaster Recommended reading: you might find the first sentence in this question useful: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/102345/using-bare-infinitive-with-verbs-such-as-see-watch-etc-present-tense-or.

Answer (score 13):

This is complicated because it depends how you interpret **heard**. In the examples below, each line shows

> what the original speaker said -> how it was reported.

It could be hear meaning **listen to**

> I heard Esther sing -> She said she heard Esther sing
>   I heard Esther singing -> She said she heard Esther singing

Or it could be hear meaning **somebody told me**

> I hear [that] Esther sings -> She said that she heard [that] Esther sings
>
> I hear [that] Esther sang - She said that she heard [that] Esther sang

There are further possibilities but they would lead to a reported sentence that includes a surplus **had**:

> I heard [that] Esther sings -> She said that she had heard [that] Esther sings
>
> I heard [that] Esther sang -> She said that she had heard [that] Esther sang

The correct answers could therefore be **sing**, **singing**, **sings** and **sang**

Comment: I'll also add that "sung" also results in a grammatically correct sentence if you interpret "Esther" to be the name of a song, as in: "She said that heard 'Esther' [being] sung." (Though of course one would normally put quote marks around it in such a case.)

Answer (score 4):

The correct choice is **sing** or **singing**.

> She said that she heard Esther sing.
>
> Or: She said that she heard Esther singing.

So at some point in the past, Esther was singing, and "she" heard Esther's voice. "Sing" is not in the past tense because the singing was happening *at the same time* as the hearing.

The only case in which it could be sang or sung is if Esther *had already sung **before** she heard about it*. However, that would sound very, very awkward, so it would be better to express that meaning like this:

> She said that she heard that Esther sang.

Answer (score 2):

Only sing or singing are correct. Sung and sang are not, because the past tense here is on the verb to hear, not to sing.