# Why is it "rob" instead of "robbed" in this sentence? "...he saw a police officer rob the man."

Tags: grammar

Why is **rob** not in the past form in this sentence?

> The witness claimed that he saw a police officer **rob** the man."

Is it not supposed to be in the past tense also?

Comment: "Rob" is an infinitive in this sentence. The construction is "see [noun phrase] [infinitive]".

Comment: Is it possible for a verb to be in an infinitive form without TO ?

Comment: Yes; it is called a "bare infinitive".

Comment: Yes, @Gugma, such verbs are therefore called bare-infinitives.

Answer (score 4):

In *The witness claimed that he saw a police officer rob the man.*, ***rob*** is used as a [bare infinitive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bare-infinitive)

Verbs which relate to our senses (eg **hear**, **watch**) are followed by bare-infinitives.

**For more:**

[Uses of the bare infinitive](https://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive-2/)

[Using bare infinitive with verbs such as “see”, “watch”, etc.: Present tense or Past Tense?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/102345/using-bare-infinitive-with-verbs-such-as-see-watch-etc-present-tense-or)